# Download a List as Excel in Spring Boot + Nextjs

Tags: spring-boot, next.js, export-to-excel

I'm trying to download a list as excel on clicking a button from my Nextjs frontend. My backend is written in Spring boot, from where I need to send the file so that user can download it on clicking the link.

My questions are:

1. What is the best practice if in this case if I want to download the file on button click?
2. What should be the return type and content type?

**The things I have already tried**: By changing content type & media type.
I think somehow I'm messing up with the content type and return type of the triggered API.

My backend code files:

ExcelExporter.java

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class ExcelExporter {
    private final XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    private XSSFSheet sheet;
    private final List<Debt> debts;

    String[] columns = {"Reference", "Title", "Descrip", "Gateway", "Status", "Amount (USD)", "Paid", "Name"};

    public ExcelExporter(List<Debt> debts) {
        this.debts = debts;
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    }


    private void writeHeaderLine() {
        sheet = workbook.createSheet("Payment Report");

        CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();

        // setting up header fonts
        XSSFFont headerFont = workbook.createFont();
        headerFont.setBold(true);
        headerFont.setFontHeight(16);

        // setting up header cell style
        headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

        // header row creation
        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

        for(int col=0; col <columns.length; col++){
            createCell(headerRow, col, columns[col], headerCellStyle);
        }

    }

    private void createCell(Row row, int columnCount, String value, CellStyle style) {
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(columnCount);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(columnCount);
        cell.setCellValue(value);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }

    private void writeDataLines() {
        int rowIdx = 1;

        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setFontHeight(14);
        style.setFont(font);

        for (Debt debt : debts) {
            Row dataRow = sheet.createRow(rowIdx++);
            int columnCount = 0;

            createCell(dataRow, columnCount++, debt.getRef(), style);
            createCell(dataRow, columnCount++, debt.getTitle(), style);
            createCell(dataRow, columnCount++, debt.getDescrip(), style);
            createCell(dataRow, columnCount++, debt.getGateway(), style);
            createCell(dataRow, columnCount++, debt.getStat(), style);
            createCell(dataRow, columnCount++, debt.getAmount(), style);
            createCell(dataRow, columnCount++, debt.getPaid(), style);
            createCell(dataRow, columnCount++, debt.getName(), style);

        }
    }

    public ByteArrayInputStream export() throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            writeHeaderLine();
            writeDataLines();
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
        }catch (IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException("fail To Import Data To Excel File: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("report")
public class ReportController {

    @GetMapping(value = "export-to-excel", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public byte[] exportReport() throws IOException {

        List<Debt> debtSummaries = new ArrayList<Debt>();
        debt.add(new Debt("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH"));
        debt.add(new Debt("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH"));
        debt.add(new Debt("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH"));
        debt.add(new Debt("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE", "FF", "GG", "HH"));
        
        DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateTime = dateFormatter.format(new Date());

        String headerKey = HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION;
        String headerValue = "attachment; filename=PaymentReport_" + currentDateTime + ".xlsx";
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add(headerKey, headerValue);

        ExcelExporter excelExporter = new ExcelExporter(debtSummaries);
        ByteArrayInputStream in = excelExporter.export();


        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}
```

Debt.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Debt {

    String ref;

    String title;

    String descrip;

    String gateway;

    String stat;

    String amount;

    String paid;

    String name;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to return ANY data from your Spring Boot app to your NextJs client, say as JSON?  From there, it seems to me the question is, how to export that data from NextJs in .csv format.

Comment: @Howard007 yes, I'm getting zip file which I think a byte array.

Comment: Then the question IS how to export the contents of that zip file to something that Excel can read, typically .csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the right approach to simply return the byte array directly. I can't guarantee you that this is the best way. But you can do it this way.

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;


@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("report")
public class ReportController {

    @GetMapping(value = "export-to-excel", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> exportReport() throws IOException {

        //Other actions you want to do... 

        ExcelExporter excelExporter = new ExcelExporter(debtSummaries);
        ByteArrayInputStream in = excelExporter.export();

        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(in.readAllBytes());

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(resource.contentLength())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
                .body(resource);
    }
}
```

Comment: from frontend it is showing **file not found**. From backend, a zip saves when I hit postman with your solution. But we are not getting the excel (which was the needed outcome in this case).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: On clicking button I have a requirement to save a list in excel. I am looking for the possible API return type for this case. I implemented your solution, but from frontend it's showing file not found error.

Comment: I updated the answer. Can you try this way?

Comment: @ImranZakhayev you create header value here `httpHeaders.add(headerKey, headerValue);` but you didn't use it
@fatih solution should be working, don't forget to add `Content-Disposition` header if you want the browser to know that this file should be downloaded